# Apache Kafka Lineage Information

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there any way to obtain lineage data for **Kafka** jobs.

Like for example we have a **Job History URL** for all the **MapReduce** jobs.

Is there anything similar for Kafka where I can get the metadata of the **Producer** producing information to a particular topic? (eg: *IP address of the producer*)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no, not for Producers.

You can list consumer client addressses, but not see producers into a topic.

One option would be to look into Apache Atlas for lineage information, which is one component of Hortonwork's [Stream Messaging Manager](https://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hortonworks-streams-messaging-manager-smm/) for analyzing Kafka connection information.

[image]

Otherwise, you would be stuck trying to enfore producers to send this data along with the messages.

Comment: But how does Atlas fetch the lineage information about Producer is what I want to know. I am looking into its source code as of now. There got to be some information with the brokers about the producers connecting to them in some logs/files or something. This is what I'm trying to figure out right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.:** I do not want any dependency for lineage info, I want to fetch raw lineage about the producers.

Comment: I haven't used Atlas. The Hortonworks SMM uses Kerberos and SASL keys combined with the `client.id` for knowing exactly which producers are communicating with a specific topic. Otherwise, each client is unauthenticated, and therefore anonymous, and they can come and go, at any given time, so you cannot accurately gather this information. If you want to gather the logs and TCP dumps separarately to built a better chart, then that is not part of the above systems